# Is it good practice to place loop invariant code outside a loop?

Tags: performance, compiler-optimization

I'm learning about loop invariant code motion as a method of code optimization in compiler design. The example used is that:

```
for ( i=0; i<n; i++ )
buffer[i] = 10*i + x*x;
```

Might as well be optimized to:

```
tmp = x*x
for (i=0; i<n; i++ )
buffer[i] = 10*i + tmp;
```

To avoid calculating x*x more than once.

In the curricular example, this is dealt with by the compiler backend.

My question is, is it generally good practice to do this explicitly in the source code (and is it more advantageous in some languages than others)?

Comment: I think you already answered your own question... _To avoid calculating x*x more than once_

Comment: When in doubt, benchmark. If it doesn't make a difference to performance, do whatever's more readable (which is entirely down to your personal taste).

Comment: I should've been more specific. The example is a case where the compiler takes the first block as input, and generates machine code equivalent to the second statement. The second is more verbose, and if the performance loss is going to be optimized away anyways, should I generally bother to put loop invariant code outside?

Comment: I tend to write code that is pretty close to SSA. In my opinion, this produces the most readable code, avoiding unnecessary mutability and overly complex expressions. That said, this only works if you give your variables good names. I would generally consider `tmp` to not be an acceptable name outside of an innermost scope.